# Reverse a formula with codependent expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I apologize for my title, but I really am a long way from understanding how to even describe my problem accurately, let alone solving it.

I'm looking to reverse this formula:

```
A       =       ?
B       =       ?
X       =   (A-FG)/FD       (Relies on A)
Y       =   FH-(B-FE)/FB    (Relies on B)
ResultA =   FB-Y*Cos(X)     (Relies on X and Y)
ResultB =   FF+Y*Sin(X)     (Relies on X and Y)

F(X)         A fixed number – I assume the value itself isn't important.
A / B        The results I wish to find
X / Y        Intermediate results that I cannot calculate
ResultA / B  Known values
```

I've looked into reversing it myself, but I get stuck trying to reverse ResultA and ResultB to get X and Y. From my limited understanding, without the values of X and Y calculated, I won't be able to work out A and B.

Is it possible to work out X and Y from ResultA and ResultB? Or are there just too many possible combinations?

If it helps, I can provide an example with values:

```
Fixed Numbers:

FA  1   FD  4   FG  7   
FB  2   FE  5   FH  8   
FC  3   FF  6           

Variables

X   0.500000    
Y   5.500000
A   9.00000000000000000000          
B   10.00000000000000000000
```

ResultA -1.826704
ResultB 8.636840

I can provide more decimal places if required.

Edit - Thank you to whoever corrected my formula. ResultB uses Sin not Cos as I originally stated.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing Result A (let's just call it $R_A$) and $FB$, you can get $Y\cos X$ by $$Y\cos X=FB-R_A$$ Similarly, from $R_B$ and $FF$ yo can get $Y\cos X$ by $$Y\cos X=R_B-FF$$ So you have two ways to get $Y\cos X$. You should get the same value, either way, but, with the numbers you have presented, you don't. You get $$FB-R_A=2--1.826=3.826,\quad R_B-FF=8.636-6=2.636$$ So something is wrong.

Anyway, just knowing $Y\cos X$ doesn't let you work out $X$ and $Y$ individually, so you can't get $A$ and $B$.